# creating space between linebreaks \n pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, replace

**Background**

I have the following `df` which contains a `Text` column that has been tokenized using `nltk` `SpaceTokenizer` to preserve `\n`

```
import pandas as pd
text =[list(['\n[PROV', 'REPORT]\nPerson', 'Name:', '\n','John', 'Dear\nProgram', 'Date:', '1/11/2000', '10:42', 'AM\nMR']), 
           list(['\nToday', 'Name:', '\n','James', 'Jay\nProgram', 'Date:', '3/11/2000', '1:45', 'PM\nmissing']), 
           list(['\n[NEWS', 'REPORT]\nPerson', 'Name:', '\n','Jane', 'Doe\nProgram', 'Date:', '3/11/2000', '1:45', 'PM\nMR']), 
           list(['\n[PROV', 'REPORT]\nPerson', 'Name:', '\n','Amy', 'Army\nProgram', 'Date:', '10/1/2000', '11:45', 'AM\nMR'])]


df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : text,
                          'ID': [1,2,3,4],
                           'P_ID': ['A','B','C','D'],

                         })

df
ID  P_ID    Text
0   1   A   [\n[PROV, REPORT]\nPerson, Name:, \n, John, Dear\nProgram, Date:, 1/11/2000, 10:42, AM\nMR]
1   2   B   [\nToday, Name:, \n, James, Jay\nProgram, Date:, 3/11/2000, 1:45, PM\nmissing]
2   3   C   [\n[NEWS, REPORT]\nPerson, Name:, \n, Jane, Doe\nProgram, Date:, 3/11/2000, 1:45, PM\nMR]
3   4   D   [\n[PROV, REPORT]\nPerson, Name:, \n, Amy, Army\nProgram, Date:, 10/1/2000, 11:45, AM\nMR]
```

Using the following code

```
df['Text'].values
```

**Output**

Gives the following output

```
array([ list(['\n[PROV', 'REPORT]\nPerson', 'Name:', '\n', 'John', 'Dear\nProgram', 'Date:', '1/11/2000', '10:42', 'AM\nMR']),
       list(['\nToday', 'Name:', '\n', 'James', 'Jay\nProgram', 'Date:', '3/11/2000', '1:45', 'PM\nmissing']),
       list(['\n[NEWS', 'REPORT]\nPerson', 'Name:', '\n', 'Jane', 'Doe\nProgram', 'Date:', '3/11/2000', '1:45', 'PM\nMR']),
       list(['\n[PROV', 'REPORT]\nPerson', 'Name:', '\n', 'Amy', 'Army\nProgram', 'Date:', '10/1/2000', '11:45', 'AM\nMR'])], dtype=object)
```

**Goal**

1) Separate `\n` (so that `\n[PROV` becomes `\n` `[PROV` and `REPORT]\nPerson` becomes `REPORT]` `\n` `Person` and  `Doe\nProgram` becomes `Doe` `\n` `Program` etc etc etc)

2) Create new column

**Tried**

```
df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].replace(r'\n',  ' \n ', regex=True)
```

**Desired Output**

Using the following code

```
df['New_Text'].values
```

I would like the following output

```
array([list(['\n', '[PROV', 'REPORT]', '\n' ,'Person', 'Name:', '\n', 'John', 'Dear', '\n', 'Program', 'Date:', '1/11/2000', '10:42', 'AM', '\n', 'MR']),
       list(['\n', 'Today', 'Name:', '\n', 'James', 'Jay', '\n', 'Program', 'Date:', '3/11/2000', '1:45', 'PM','\n', 'missing']),
       list(['\n', '[NEWS', 'REPORT]','\n', 'Person', 'Name:', '\n', 'Jane', 'Doe', '\n', 'Program', 'Date:', '3/11/2000', '1:45', 'PM', '\n', 'MR']),
       list(['\n', '[PROV', 'REPORT]', '\n', 'Person', 'Name:', '\n', 'Amy', 'Army', '\n', 'Program', 'Date:', '10/1/2000', '11:45', 'AM', '\n', 'MR'])], dtype=object)
```

**Question**

How do I achieve my desired output?

Comment: could you find something to load/parse your `text` a bit better, it looks very strange at the moment and would probably save a lot of work down the line

Comment: @SamMason the text has been tokenized. I think that's why it is in the format that it is in. Is that what you are referring to when you say it looks "very strange"?

Comment: what sort of tokenization is this?  if you're doing any sort of NLP I wouldn't expect there to be line breaks in the middle of "words"

Comment: `SpaceTokenizer` to preserve the `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird structure, but can achieve with some [mappings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

```
import itertools as it
import re

df['split'] = list(map(lambda text: list(filter(lambda b: b, list(it.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: re.split(r'(\n)', x), text))))), df.Text))
```